# Testing $loaded in Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, karma-runner

I'm working with firebase and angular and I have this function in my controller and I have a test written for it which is passing but I find the test doesn't cover the $loaded portion, How do I test the $loaded part. I used $loaded because firebase returns an object which contains a promise.

Here is the function in my controller

```
    $scope.find = function() {
   var uid = $rootScope.currentUser ? ($stateParams.uid || $rootScope.currentUser.uid) : $stateParams.uid;
   if (uid) {
      console.log(uid, 'uid');
      var fellow = User.find(uid);
         if (fellow) {
            console.log(fellow, 'fellow');
            fellow.$loaded(function(data) {
             $scope.fellow = data;
             $scope.uploadedResult = $scope.fellow.videoUrl;
             console.log(data.level, 'level');
             if(data.level){
                $scope.level = Levels.find(data.level);
             }
            });
         }
    }
```

};

Take Note User is a service that has find method that I'm injecting in my controller .

Here's the test I have which is passing

```
describe('matsi.controller test', function() {
```

var User,
 scope,
 ctrl;

```
 beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $cookies, $injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Fellow = $injector.get('Fellow');
    Log = $injector.get('Log');
    MailService = $injector.get('MailService');
    stateParams = $injector.get('$stateParams');
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    Levels = $injector.get('Levels');
    User = $injector.get('User');
    $location = $injector.get('$location');
     rootScope.currentUser = {
                uid: 'uid',
                fullName: 'Happy fellow'
            };
    ctrl = $controller('FellowCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $rootScope: scope
    });
    $cookies.rootRef = 'https://brilliant-heat-9512.firebaseio.com/';
}));
```

});

```
it('should expect find to have been called', function() {
    scope.currentUser = {
        uid: 'uid'
    };
    spyOn(User, 'find');
    scope.find();
    expect(User.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});